# Plotting for repeated values using loops Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have some data that looks like `data = pd.read_csv(....)`:

```
Year    Month     HOUR  NAME            RATE
2010    1          0    Big              222  
2010    1          0    Welsch Power     434
2010    1          0    Cottonwood       124
2010    1          1    Big              455  
2010    1          1    Welsch Power     900
2010    1          1    Cottonwood       110
.
.
.
2010    2          0    Big              600  
2010    2          0    Welsch Power     1000
2010    2          0    Cottonwood       170
.
.
2010    3          0    Big              400  
2010    3          0    Welsch Power     900
2010    3          0    Cottonwood       110
```

As you can see the HOUR ( 0 - 23 ) repeats itself every Month ( 0 - 12 ). I need a way to loop through values so I can plot the *RATE* *(Y-Axis)* every Month by the HOUR *(X-Axis)* for each NAME.

My attempt looks like:

```
for name, data in data.groupby('NAME'):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,23))
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.plot(data['HOUR'], data['RATE'], label=name)
    plt.xlabel('Hour')
    plt.ylabel('Rate')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

This works but because HOUR repeats every change in month the graphs end up back at 0 every time it loops. I want to have each of the 12 Months as separate lines in different colors for each NAME on one graph but currently they look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.pivot` your `DataFrame` after the groupby so it will plot each month as a different line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for name, gp in df.groupby(['NAME']):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    gp.pivot(index='HOUR', columns='Month', values='RATE').plot(ax=ax, marker='o', title=name)
    plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This works but I actually would like separate graphs for each of the NAMEs (there are actually 20 NAMEs with 12 months each).

Comment: This is great. Thank you.

Comment: Any way to change the font size of the title along with adding some extra text outside of just the name?

Comment: Yes, `ax` is a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` object, which has a ton of methods associated with it. You can remove `title=name` from the plot and instead, within the loop do something like `ax.set_title(name+'_more_text', fontsize=16, color='orange')`. You can do endless customization with `matplotlib`, so probably best to explore a few of their examples